# Recursive infer with generic types

Tags: typescript

The setup:

```js
export type SchemaOne<T> =
  | Entity<T>
  | SchemaObjectOne<T>;
export interface SchemaObjectOne<T> {
  [key: string]: SchemaOne<T>;
}
export type SchemaOf<T> = T extends SchemaOne<infer R> ? R : never;

const sch: Entity<ArticleResource> = ArticleResource.getEntitySchema();
const a = { a: sch  };
const aa: SchemaOne<ArticleResource> = a;
// works!
type Z = SchemaOf<typeof a>;
// Z is ArticleResource as expected

const b = { a: { b: sch }  };
type ZZ = SchemaOf<typeof b>;
// ZZ is unknown - SADBEAR
```

So I have my recursive definition matching correctly (methodology stolen from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3496#issuecomment-128553540). (hence the works after aa definition). However, now I want to be able to infer the type even without making it more general. (getting bb's type).

So for some reason this works only one level deep. Is this a limitation of typescript? Is there some sort of recursion with infer I can use to actually find the generic type?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the compiler actually goes about [inferring](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#type-inference-in-conditional-types) conditional types.  I'm not surprised that there would be a limit to how many type instantiations it does before it gives up with `unknown` (or `any`).  Since `infer R` by itself doesn't do it for you, I'd suggest coming up with your own way of inspecting a type to determine what, if any, `R` should be returned for a given type.

First of all I'm defining these so that it compiles... your own types are likely different, but they're not in the question statement (so I get to pick them, right? ... right?)

```
// Making these up

interface Entity<T> {
  e: T;
}

class ArticleResource {
  static getEntitySchema<T>(): Entity<T> {
    return null!;
  }
  ar = "ArticleResource";
}
```

Here's one possible implementation of `SchemaOf<T>`:

```
type _SchemaOf<T> = T extends Entity<infer R>
  ? R
  : T extends object ? { [K in keyof T]: _SchemaOf<T[K]> }[keyof T] : never;
```

(I'm naming it `_SchemaOf` because I will use it to build my final `SchemaOf`).  Here, if `T` is just `Entity<R>` for some `R`, then return `R`.  That's should work well.  Otherwise, check if `T` is an `object`.  If not, then just return `never`.  (This allows us to short-circuit to `never` if we're checking against a primitive type).  Otherwise, calculate the union of `_SchemaOf<T[K]>` for every key `K` of `T`.  (Possible warning: This type doesn't seem to count as a circular conditional type, and does not result in a compiler error, but I'm not sure if it's exactly legal.  See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26980) for a discussion of circular conditional types.)

So, `_SchemaOf<Entity<A>>` should just be `A`, and `_SchemaOf<{a: X, b: Y, c: Z}>` should be equivalent to `_SchemaOf<X> | _SchemaOf<Y> | _SchemaOf<Z>`.  That will end up recursing down through the object types and pulling out all `Entity` types and getting a union of them.

That's nearly what you want, but it does return some weird answers when you pass in something that's not a `SchemaOne<T>` for any `T`, like `_SchemaOf<{a: Entity<A>, b: string}>`.  That will give you just `A`, even though `{a: Entity<A>, b: string}` is not a `SchemaOne<A>`.

So we do a sanity check like this:

```
type SchemaOf<T> = T extends SchemaOne<_SchemaOf<T>> ? _SchemaOf<T> : never;
```

We check the result of `_SchemaOf<T>` to make sure that `SchemaOne<_SchemaOf<T>>` matches `T`.  If so, great.  If not, we get `never`.

Let's test it out:

```
type Z = SchemaOf<typeof a>;
// Z is ArticleResource as expected

const b = { a: { b: sch } };
type ZZ = SchemaOf<typeof b>;
// ZZ is ArticleResource too
```

That works for you.  And then:

```
const c = { a: { b: sch, c: "string" } };
type _C = _SchemaOf<typeof c>; // ArticleResource
type C = SchemaOf<typeof c>; // never
```

This rejects `c`, as I think you'd want.  And, to see the union stuff:

```
const d = { a: sch, b: null! as Entity<string> };
type D = SchemaOf<typeof d>; // string | ArticleResource
const dd: SchemaOne<D> = d; // okay
```

Okay, hope that helps you proceed.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEFkEMGsEsDsDmoAuALApgZw6ArgA4BQRCKGATgGaQDGuAovCrCgJ4A8AKgHygDeRUKAwAuUFwDcRAL4laAG0hYsoAIIUWijACVsAezwV6AoaCwpIW0IgwomLdgGVamALaRuPABQBKcQ6snLymwsIUdkbwoPB4CgoAhNLCcsKQFKAAvKAARBpaCroGRvQ50nJEGAAeBPqaqGwEuC7ukADy8BheWaCB7N0APqAtGB5tAEYAVhi0KB1dvNLVtfVklDQmI2NTM3Od3YLCANrQGGziFhQIiAC64lvt+4uyJOxNoAD6D21U3dlcIiq5HgABNVH1OAgqJRQDoeGYAPywsziAHVYFg0D6HazUBI-igI4AaVACFApzY+ioEjun2+vy4xJufBkJzOVJpoHEnQAbpRpEQ3s1XKN2gy+P9ARjVN99l8RWNxXwkfLWj9utyMHyKALaPp4BZzK4Aswghx8rBtHosIZjBgJepNJbCtbbfQAHS2eym5wKyB+aR6g0oUCQHoEyAXVygGTSIWgACaPXpHCFHMgPED+sNkEjwz983NTqtxTtDsg0hAoAA7nVoFgEoLGrgAFrJgu-NPUjOVsBt2CqC0lm0lXDKQFNWYYEHybMh8bh0PiAnjKNoGMxuPN0AttvZFNd0DjTNEKu70mD4su0v0WfB0C0Rd5ldrgA0D-EOUu1xyG9jTfeD4AGEelVUV1UPWhM1AKsh2vEc7QA3AQP3DtU2bDkoMkGCwF5Sg70NEEnzfI9uTiRJQ3BH1OG-JAWS3d4ABF2zVTsMOpEFoKrWjkCGOCigQ28g0IkF7gLfZGIdEFsKrfRoEgNgiCAA)